# Conexão Visual Studio 2019 c# com Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase

Tentei horas e até dias procurar exemplos de aplicação para extensões de conexão do VS 2019 (em C#) com o Firebase, mas, sem nenhum sucesso. Sinto que quase ninguém usa por falta de informação mais detalhada.

Baixei as extensões FirebaseAuthentication.net, FirebaseDatabase.net e também do FireSharp no Visual Studio, mas a documentação é muito superficial e não estou conseguindo utilizar.

Exemplo:

1. Enviar e buscar informação de autenticação do usuário com e-mail e senha
2. Acessar os nós e seus filhos para leitura e escrita.
3. O que significa `.StartAt(???)` `.LimitToFirst(???)` `.OnceAsync();` (*do* `FirebaseDatabase.net`)
4. Principais propriedades de cada `using` necessários.
5. Como buscar e enviar o comando `push` de `id` único pelo Firebase.

**Exemplo:**

```
var firebase = new Firebase
    .Database
    .FirebaseClient("https://fir-app-20502.firebaseio.com/");    
var idUser = await firebase
    .Child("CSharp")
    .OrderByKey()
    .StartAt(???)
    .LimitToFirst(???)
    .OnceAsync<???>();
```

Andei vendo alguns vídeos de um indiano sobre o Firesharp, mas, não tem nada sobre autenticação.

Comment: no link do [firebase-database-dotnet)](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet) tem vários exemplos inclusive sobre [authentication](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet)

Comment: Olá amigo. Esta é justamente a documentação oficial que não está clara. Tentei usar mas, não funciona, pois, não entendi os exemplos, como no código de exemplo acima (???).

Comment: faça algumas tentativas para eliminar sistematicamente possíveis erros:

Comment: o firebase tem um 'console' para testar consultas no seu banco de dados... teste antes lá...

Comment: você pode preencher alguns dados no banco de dados, e torna-los legíveis por qualquer um (read = true), e tentar acessa-los sem autenticação, para confirmar que sua consulta funciona

Comment: eu já usei está api no node.js/browser, mas encontrei algo que pode ajuda-lo: [https://medium.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-c-library-8e5e1c30acc2](https://medium.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-c-library-8e5e1c30acc2) , rolando para baixo você vai encontrar dois tópicos que devem ser de seu interesse: "Authenticate with third-party entity" e "Authenticate with email and password"

Comment: mas infelizmente não oficial